# How do I ensure custom post type information is displayed in correct order?

Tags: custom-post-types

I would like to display some category archives below whatever the user has typed in on a custom post type. How do I make sure that the user's content displays above mine?

Comment: Where do you want to show these archives? Front-end? Back-end? In your own theme?

Comment: I would like to show these archives on the front end. What I am trying to do is basically put some information about a given category above the posts from that category. So I will make a custom post type, display the post content at the top, and then have the category posts start to display below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, I used `add_filter( 'the_content', 'myFunction' );`

Then in my function, I echoed `the_content()` to display the content the user typed in and then echoed the other content I needed.